# make sure graphics device gets closed

Tags: r, plot

I am closing the device (here: pdf() ) I am plotting to at the end of my function with dev.off(). However, if the function/loop terminates due to an error the device stays open. When a function gets repeatedly called, this can lead to quite a lot of open devices; and file handles.

How can I make sure the device gets closed even if the function fails?

I do remember that I once saw how to do this, but I cannot remember.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`on.exit()` is made for situations just like this. It's good practice to use it whenever opening a (file or other) connection in a non-interactive setting.

```
f <- function() {
    pdf(tempfile()) # tempfile() so example doesn't clutter up working directory.
    on.exit(dev.off())
    plot(randomNonExistentObjectName)
}

f()
# Error in plot(randomNonExistentObjectName) : 
#   object 'randomNonExistentObjectName' not found

dev.list()
# NULL
```

Comment: Ha! That was the one, I was looking for! :-) Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Wrap your whole plotting expression into a `tryCatch` like so:

```
tryCatch(expr={pdf(...); plot(...)}, finally=dev.off())
```

Comment: This doesn't work as expected if you get an error in the `pdf(...)` call itself: you might close an other opened device, if any is opened.

Comment: @Calimo Wouldn't the same be the case for the answer by Josh O'Brien?

Comment: @Mihai No. In Josh's answer, if the call to `pdf()` fails, `on.exit` will not be executed and therefore `dev.off` will not be triggered.

Comment: @Calimo, yes, indeed, that seems to be the case. Thanks for taking the time to answer!